# How can I use git with ssh on bitbucket

Tags: git, macos, ssh

I want to use git on bitbucket with ssh connection but `git clone` returns fatal error.

I created a repository named sshtest and I'm sure using correct ssh key because I confirm it with ssh commands like following.

Do you have some ideas to raise the error?

```
$ ssh -T git@bitbucket.org # show nothing
$ ssh git@bitbucket.org 
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
logged in as username.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
Connection to bitbucket.org closed.

$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:username/sshtest.git
Cloning into 'sshtest'...
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 0):

I replicated the steps you outline with my own Bitbucket account, test repo, and key, and it worked without any problems:

```
[ville@UBUNTU16-ORBITER:~/Projects] [16:37 CST]
# git clone git@bitbucket.org:vwal/testrepo.git            
Cloning into 'testrepo'...
Enter passphrase for key '/home/ville/.ssh/keys/gitkey/gitkey': 
remote: Counting objects: 65, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (36/36), done.
remote: Total 65 (delta 17), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (65/65), 4.85 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (17/17), done.
[ville@UBUNTU16-ORBITER:~/Projects] [16:38 CST]
```

This leads me to think something is still wrong with your repository access settings on the Bitbucket side (with the user configured you'd be able to connect to Bitbucket – as in your test – but not to the specific repository). Are you sure you have given the accessing username sufficient access to the `sshtest` repository in Bitbucket? You can do so by going to your repository in Bitbucket, then select **Settings > User and group access**, and give the accessing username at least *read* access.

Comment: thank you for the information. the `sshtest` repository is my own repository, so I have a Admin right and the setting said "username already has access".
Strangely, I could clone the repository from windows via sourcetree with ssh authentication.